# Java return Object

Tags: java, object, interface, return

I don’t know how to return the value of the string here, in short, I need the output of this string that is stored in the function:

```
public  Object Directory(String directory) {
    String directory1 = "directory";
    return directory1;
 }
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(directory1);
}
```

This is my interface in another file:

```
public interface Interface extends Remote {

    Object FileName(String filename) throws RemoteException;
    Object Directory(String directory) throws RemoteException;

}
```

Comment: You are already returning the String casted as an Object. What are you asking?

Comment: You need to call the function after crating an instance, and fix the return type.

Comment: @jbx More simply, how can I get the value of a string stored in public  Object Directory(String directory).

Comment: 1. It seems you are starting with Java, its good to get to know few concepts(try a simple course in java online or some book) 2. Create the object , 3. Invoke the method Dictionary ("some word") , 4. print the retuned value (you are already returning it). 5. Understand the meaning of local variable (can't be accessed from other methods). 6. understand the difference between static methods vs instance method. 7. Know the Good practices, start with good naming conventions

Comment: A function does not "store" any value. Values are stored in variables. You call the function to execute some computation and the value is then returned once to the caller.

Comment: You should definitely study [the basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java you must declare the return type of a function. In your case you have defined the return type of `Object` when you really want a return type of `String`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you. You can try so.

```
public static String Directory(String directory) {
    String directory1 = "directory";
    return directory1;
}
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(Directory("directory1"));
}
```

Comment: you understand me but your answer is false eclipse says delete static from public static String Directory(String directory) and if possible you don't change function

Comment: it works for me in IntelliJ Idea. but if you want non-static. You can do so.
public class Test {

    public Object Directory(String directory) {
        String directory1 = "directory";
        return directory1;
    }
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        Test t = new Test();
        System.out.println(t.Directory("directory1"));
    }
}